# How to limit max characters in a line for textarea in extjs?

Tags: extjs4, textarea, extjs4.1

I am using extjs **Ext.form.field.TextArea (xtype: textareafield, textarea)**. I want to limit max characters in a line to 50.
I am using this to add options dynamically to a radio group, i.e. each line will be added as a separate option to the radio group.

How can I limit characters in a line for textarea? I found some answers in jQuery and plain HTML here but I am looking for an extjs way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to impose maxlength on textArea in HTML using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125482/how-to-impose-maxlength-on-textarea-in-html-using-javascript)

Comment: give "answers in jQuery and plain HTML" and i will put it in Ext.form.field.TextArea as extjs way

Comment: link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292235/max-characters-in-textarea-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Setting **maxlength** for textareafield.

```
           {
                xtype: 'textareafield',
                name: 'user_message',
                id: 'user_message',
                height:150,
                maxLength : 50,
                margin:'5 10 22 10',
                fieldLabel: "Message"
            }
```

Comment: Wrong. This will limit length of all text in textarea, not in the line.