# Limit the Characters in textarea in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to Limit the characters in a textare in jquery .here is my jquery code

```
$('#editnote-tooltip-wrapper').appendTo($(this).closest('.editnote-tip-wrapper')).fadeIn(300).css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'left': 0, 'top': 0, 'z-index': '10000' }).find('.content').html('<textarea cols="5" rows="5" class="elastic" style="overflow: hidden; height: 150px;"></textarea>' + $html);
```

how can I make this possible.anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean by 'limit'? Do you want to add a validation prohibiting entering too many characters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [textarea character limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533053/textarea-character-limit)

Comment: Another duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292235/max-characters-in-textarea-with-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to limit the character you can just use **maxlength** attribute of html. like `<textarea cols="5" rows="5" class="elastic" style="overflow: hidden; height: 150px;" maxlength="500"></textarea>`

anyhow it is not going to work in ie9 but you can follow the below code.

```
<form name="myform">
<textarea name="limitedtextarea" onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.limitedtextarea,this.form.countdown,100);" onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.limitedtextarea,this.form.countdown,100);">
</textarea><br>
<font size="1">(Maximum characters: 100)<br>
You have <input readonly type="text" name="countdown" size="3" value="100"> characters left.</font>
</form>
```

Refer [this page!!.](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/form/limit-characters.html) for more info.

Comment: Didn't know someone still use font element and size attributes in 2013 :)

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery Limit](http://unwrongest.com/projects/limit/) is a lightweight plugin (~6 Kb) "that limits the number of characters that can be entered in a textarea or input field. The plugin can also report the number of characters left before the user reaches the length limit."

Only two elements are needed: a textarea or input field, and another element (in the below example, a span) to display how many characters are available. Its super simple and easy to use.

```
You have <span id="charsLeft"></span> chars left.
<textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#myTextarea').limit('140','#charsLeft');
</script>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/janjarfalk/4kS65/) | [on Github](https://github.com/janjarfalk/jquery.limit.js)

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this [link](http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/jquery-tips-tricks-how-to-limit-characters-inside-a-textarea/) which has the details and a sample. you can give [this](http://jsfiddle.net/p43BH/1/) a try. code is

```
    $(document).ready( function() {        
        var maxLen = 10;

        $('#send-txt').keypress(function(event){
            var Length = $("#send-txt").val().length;
            var AmountLeft = maxLen - Length;
            $('#txt-length-left').html(AmountLeft);
            if(Length >= maxLen){
                if (event.which != 8) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: This doesn't take pasting text into account.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely working for me.

```
<textarea name="txtScript" id="word_count" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<br>
Total word Count : <span id="display_count">0</span> words. Words left : <span id="word_left">10</span>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#word_count").on('keydown', function(e) {
        var words = $(this).val().length;
        if (words <= 10) {
            $('#display_count').text(words);
            $('#word_left').text(10-words)
        }else{
            if (e.which !== 8) e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, `.on('keydown'...` was a bit more clean for me.

Answer (score 0):

you may use maxlength attribute for the textarea

For example this one will limit characters to 10

```
.html('<textarea maxlength="10" cols="5" rows="5" class="elastic" style="overflow: hidden; height: 150px;"></textarea>' + $html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that the user can also past text. Using keypress is wrong, you will have to use the keyup event like so:

```
    $('#my-textarea').keyup(function(event){
        var $field = $('#my-textarea');
        var $left = $('#my-textarea-length-left');
        var len = $field.val().length;
        if (len >= 300) {
            $field.val( $field.val().substring(0, 299) );
            $left.text(0);
            if (event.which != 8) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        $left.text(300 - len);
    });
```

This limits the textarea with id "my-textarea" to 300 characters and shows the amount left in a span or div with the id "my-textarea-length-left".

It properly handles text paste.

HTML Markup:

```
<textarea rows="4" id="my-textarea"></textarea>
<span id="my-textarea-length-left"></span>
```