# how to restrict the user to enter only 250 words in text area?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, textarea

i have created one form for user to submit a abstract. but while submitting i need to check weather they have added more than 250 words or not. i need to allow only 250 words . how to do this ?

i have tried some JavaScript but it works for only 250 character.

here is my code

```
function maxlength(element, maxvalue)
   {
  var q = eval("document.upload."+element+".value.length");
   var r = q - maxvalue;
   var msg = "Sorry, you have input "+q+" characters into the "+
  "text area box you just completed. It can return no more than "+
  maxvalue+" words to be processed. Please abbreviate "+
 "your text by at least "+r+" words";
    if (q > maxvalue) alert(msg);
      }
```

and my textarea is :

```
  <tr>
   <td><label>Abstract Details</label> </td>
 <td><label>Please enter data, at most 250 words:</label>
  <br/><textarea rows="6" cols="80"name="box_name"   onChange="maxlength('box_name', 250)" style="width: 257px; height: 131px;">    </textarea></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
```

how to limit for 250 words .

thanks in advance

Comment: So you would like to allow `250 words` not `characters ?

Comment: Take a look to given link, Answer is available : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395785/limit-the-characters-in-textarea-in-jquery

Comment: Just split with `textarea`'s value with `space` and verify the `length` with `maxlength`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909646/counting-and-limiting-words-in-a-textarea here you go first link from google when you search for it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To prevent submitting form when there is more than 250 characters in the textarea, add `id="box_id"` to your textarea and add this event to form element:

```
onsubmit="return maxlength(getElementById('box_id'), 250);
```

Now in your function split this value by multiple spaces:

```
function maxlength(element, maxvalue){
    var q = element.value.split(/[\s]+/).length;
    if(q > maxvalue){
        var r = q - maxvalue;
        alert("Sorry, you have input "+q+" words into the "+
        "text area box you just completed. It can return no more than "+
        maxvalue+" words to be processed. Please abbreviate "+
        "your text by at least "+r+" words");
        return false;
    }
}
```

To take advantage from new HTML attributes, you can also add "pattern" attribute to textarea with regex limiting input to 250 words:

```
<textarea rows="6" cols="80"name="box_name"   onChange="maxlength(this, 250)" style="width: 257px; height: 131px;" 
    pattern="^(?:\b\w+\b[\s\r\n]*){1,250}$">
</textarea>
```

This regex pattern was taken from following SO thread, which touches similar problem with 250 words: [Limit the number of words in a response with a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557695/limit-the-number-of-words-in-a-response-with-a-regular-expression)

Comment: there was an extra semicolon in alert, after "words" - I removed it and tested, now it works. I also edited your msg text - changed word "characters" to "words"

Comment: ya its working now . but the problem while submitting or  on change it will show error msg if i entered more than 250 words . but after closing that alert msg its allowing to submit .(if  word is more than 250 all so. ) how to fix it

Comment: I edited the answer - the function must be invoked on submitting and return false to prevent submission.

Comment: then i no need to use onchnage in textarea ?

Comment: you don't need, delete onchange from textarea, but add `id` to reference it in form onsubmit event.

Comment: I tried it also, works perfectly. Add return false after alert and return before `maxlength` function to return false in case of failure.

Answer (score 1):

If you want 250 characters, You can set the maxlength attribute to 250

if you want 250 words:

```
function maxlength(obj,wordLen){
   var len = obj.value.split(/[\s]+/);
   if(len.length > wordLen){
       alert("You cannot put more than "+wordLen+" words in this text area.");
   }
 }
```

**Function Call:**

```
onChange="maxlength(this, 250)"
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2h465m55/)**

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
function maxlength(element, maxvalue)
{
    var value = $(elment).val();
    var words = value.split(' ');

    var msg = 'Sorry, you have input ' + words.length + ' words into the ' +
        'text area you just completed. It can return no more than ' +
        maxvalue + ' words to be processed. Please abbreviate ' +
        'your text by at least ' + (words.length - maxvalue) + ' words';

    if (words.length > maxvalue) {
        alert(msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement `eval("document.upload." + element + ".value.length")` will return no of `characters` not `words`, if you want to limit `250 words` then just split `value of textarea` with `space` and verify it with `max words allowed` and then return appropriate message:

You may try this code.

```
function maxlength(element, maxvalue) {
    var q = eval("document.upload." + element + ".value");
    var textLength = q.split(/\S+/).length - 1
    var r = textLength - maxvalue;
    var msg = "Sorry, you have input " + textLength + " characters into the " +
        "text area box you just completed. It can return no more than " + maxvalue + " words to be processed. Please abbreviate " +
        "your text by at least " + r + " words";
    if (textLength > maxvalue) alert(msg);
}
```