# IE 7 Set MaxLength For TextArea Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I have HTML and javascript code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
         $("#test").attr("maxlength", "15");
         $("#test").attr("xxx", "15");
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="test" ></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is :

Why this code : `$("#test").attr("maxlength", "15");` give me an error :

> Member not found File: jquery.js, Line: 2582, Column: 4

But this code : $("#test").attr("xxx", "15"); doesn't throw an error.

I am using IE 7

Comment: A `textarea` field has no `maxlength` property. I would imagine that's why IE7 is throwing an error. To limit the number of characters in a `textarea` you have to do it manually using the `keypress` event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292235/max-characters-in-textarea-with-jquery

Comment: What version of jQuery?

Comment: jquery version : 1.9.1

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : but why `$("#test").attr("xxx", "15");` doesn't throw an error?

Comment: Ah, I thought `xxx` was just a placeholder. I'm not sure. Either way the `maxlength` attribute is invalid, and won't achieve what you want. Check the top answer in the question I linked to.

Comment: Yes i know maxlength is not compatible in IE 7 but i want to know why `$("#test").attr("xxx", "15");` doesn't throw an error.