# Prevent Addition input

Tags: javascript, events, input, onchange, keyboard-events

I want to stop taking input in the text field once 10 characters have been entered.

What I have so far is not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#comment').keypress(function(event){

    if ($('#comment').val()).length == 10) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

  });
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [max characters in textarea with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292235/max-characters-in-textarea-with-jquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this.  Use the `maxlength` attribute instead.  It can be used with `input` or `textarea` elements:

```
<input id="comment" maxlength="2" type="text">
<textarea maxlength="100"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **maxlength** attribute of the **input** tag
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp

Comment: I think he means `textarea`